# Power of 10 with Python Sympy and Latex

Tags: python, latex, sympy

This is probably trivial, but I can't find the answer. Consider the following code:

```py
from sympy import *
X = Symbol('X')
a=10
b=100
c=1000
d=10000
s = latex ( a*b*c*d / X  )
print (s)
```

displays:

```
\frac{10000000000}{X}
```

And I would prefer

```
\frac{10^{10}}{X}
```

Is it possible ? Note that a, b, c and d are read from files. So values will change at each run. Then, following stuffs don't solve my problem:

```
n20 = Symbol('10')
```

neither

```
latex(S('10**10/X', evaluate=False))
```

Comment: Declare `n20 = Symbol('20')` and use it in your equation.

Comment: I updated the quesiton. I can't use your proposal.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('X')
X
>>> latex(S('10**20/X', evaluate=False))
'\\frac{10^{20}}{X}'
```

See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Quick-examples.

EDIT: Your edited question differs considerably from the original. Here's an answer to it.

Because your input values might not be powers of ten `r` might not be. Consequently, when it is expressed as a power of ten its exponent might not be an integer; hence, the use of base ten logarithms.

```
from sympy import latex, sympify, Symbol
from math import log10

a=10
b=100
c=1000
d=10000

r = a * b * c * d
exponent = log10(r)

X = Symbol('X')

s = latex(sympify('10**{}/X'.format(exponent), evaluate=False))
print (s)
```

The result for these values of `a, b, c` and `d` is `\frac{10^{10.0}}{X}`.

Comment: It's not working with 1000*100*10*100*1000*100000*10000

Comment: It gives the proper latex output for me: `10 \cdot 100 \cdot 100 \cdot 1000 \cdot 1000 \cdot 10000 \cdot 100000`

Comment: @chrisz: Thanks, I neglected to check that.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear, what I expect is not 10 \cdot 100 \cdot 100 \cdot 1000 \cdot 1000 \cdot 10000 \cdot 100000 it is \frac{10^{20}}{X}

Comment: @Fifi there isn't a built in way to handle what you want. You will have to come up with some custom way to get the components you want from an equation before using `latex`

Comment: @BillBell I get the same thing when I use that command.  The command I used to get my above output was: `latex(S('1000*100*10*100*1000*100000*10000', evaluate=False))`

Comment: @chrisz: I need to take more of my anti-confusion medication.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a little help that will return your number with powers of 10 removed. Then wrap this in an unevaluated Mul and pass it to latex:

```
>>> def u10(n):
...  if abs(n) < 10 or int(n) != n: return n
...  s = str(n)
...  m = s.rstrip('0')
...  if len(m) == len(s): return n
...  return Mul(int(m), Pow(10, len(s) - len(m), evaluate=0), evaluate=0)
...
>>> u10(12300)
123*10**2
>>> latex(Mul(_,1/x,evaluate=False))
'\\frac{123 \\cdot 10^{2}}{x}'�
```